# How can I send a gesture from activity

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I'm trying to send a gesture when I clicking on the button but nothing happens why?

I made the gesture position top the button to check if that works or no.

I enabled accessibility permissions.

**Main Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyService myService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        if (myService == null)
            myService = new MyService();
        Log.w("ABC", String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(1000)));
    }

}
```

**MyService Class**

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService {

    public MyService() {
        clickOnPosition(540, 960);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
    }

    private void clickOnPosition(float x, float y) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        GestureDescription.StrokeDescription strokeDescription = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 4000, 1000);
        GestureDescription.Builder builder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
        builder.addStroke(strokeDescription);
        dispatchGesture(builder.build(), new GestureResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
                Log.w("ABC", "Completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
                Log.w("ABC", "Canceled");
            }
        }, null);
    }

}
```

> Note: It works if I moved clickOnPosition(540, 960); to onServiceConnected()

Comment: You cannot create a new instance of `MyService()` manually via its constructor. The system needs to create the service -- in the case of an `AccessibilityService`, that would be by the user enabling it in Settings.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I know and I enable accessibility permission from settings, But how can I start gestures when I click the button? Not when enabled accessibility permission from settings

Comment: You might try [the bound service pattern](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) to talk to your already-running instance of the service.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, I'll take look at it. Thank you, Regards

Comment: @CommonsWare Everything is working now but can you tell me how can resend the gesture after calling `onCompleted` method?